# In Java, how should I declare the return type if a recursive method can return mixed values?

Tags: java, android, json, return, type-conversion

I have the following method definition which is intended to search a JSON object for a given key and return either the JSONObject or the String value of that key. To ensure it searches through every level of the JSON object I have made it recursive, but only in the event that a deeper JSONObject can be returned. The compiler complains that this must return an Object because I have declared that return type. Fine. In two cases I am returning an object but I think its problem is that in some circumstances it will not return anything. If I add a final return false, or something, it will pass the compiler check but a call to this method will always then (eventually) return false making it useless. I am not used to a strictly typed language like Java so I haven't encountered a similar issue before. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
public Object find(String contentId, JSONObject node) {
    JSONObject currentNode = (node != null) ? node : this.txtContent;
    Iterator<?> nodeKeys = currentNode.keys();

    while ( nodeKeys.hasNext() ){

        try {
            String key = (String) nodeKeys.next();

            if (key.equals(contentId)) {
                if (currentNode.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                    return currentNode.getJSONObject(key);
                } else {
                    return currentNode.getString(key);
                }
            } else if (currentNode.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                find(contentId, currentNode.getJSONObject(key));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would the method always eventually return false? (Note that returning `null` would normally be more appropriate than returning `false` here...) And why do you not do anything with the value returned by the recursive call to `find`?

Comment: It would always return false because I wasn't doing anything with the returned value from find(), as you pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see, you should use the value returned by the find call and return null if not found:

```
public Object find(String contentId, JSONObject node) {
    JSONObject currentNode = (node != null) ? node : this.txtContent;
    Iterator<?> nodeKeys = currentNode.keys();

    while ( nodeKeys.hasNext() ){

        try {
            String key = (String) nodeKeys.next();

            if (key.equals(contentId)) {
                if (currentNode.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                    return currentNode.getJSONObject(key);
                } else {
                    return currentNode.getString(key);
                }
            } else if (currentNode.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                Object foundObj = find(contentId, currentNode.getJSONObject(key));
                if (foundObj!=null) {
                    return foundObj;
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I see. I would normally return the call to find (e.g. return find()) but that seemed to cause different return type problems in this instance. I think that's what was throwing me off. Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: No problem, I have had these kind of problems before.

Answer (score 1):

The `Either` class was made for situations just like this.  See [the documentation here](http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/fj/data/Either.html)

Usage:

```
Either<OneResultType,OtherResultType> result;
```

This avoids expensive instanceOf checks.  Return `null` if the object is not found.

Answer (score 0):

add return null; below the while loop

Answer (score 0):

This method would only keep returning false if it kept hitting the else if constantly until the while loop condition ends and you get to your "return false".

Instead of return false have return null; at the very end and in the calling method have a check to see if the returned object was null which means nothing was found